# Is there a JavaScript console limit in WebKit?

Tags: javascript, qt, webkit, qtwebkit, console.log

I want to limit the memory or the number of entries in the JavaScript / Web Inspector console.

Is it already limited somehow (except by available and accessible memory)?

If not, is it possible to just clear out the oldest entries in the console log while retaining newer ones, i.e. something like `console.clear(10000)`?

Is there anything like a limit or a selective `clear()` in any JavaScript engine?

The issue is that I want to log debug information in a single-page app in an embedded web view but do not want to constantly leak memory this way.

Comment: How significant do you think the memory usage of the dev console is?

Comment: Just a hint: running `var i=0;setInterval(function(){console.log({ x : i++ });},5)` for 10000 iterations resulted (for me) in roughly 80MB of memory usage. That's quite a _lot_ of logs for a relatively insignificant amount of memory.

Comment: Depends on how much you log, how many objects and other big stuff you log, for how long... if an app is running for days, weeks or longer (you could just switch the computer to standby and resume work), without being restarted, or if we log more data, it may be significant enough. And 10,000 is not much... think 100,000, or 1,000,000.

Comment: Then I'd suggest simply running a `clean()` on a daily interval. Besides, who's going to look at the console log in a application? Do you really need the log to be filled in the first place, during normal operation?

Comment: It makes debugging easier, because you do not have to try reproducing an error but can dive right in while it is happening. And according to Murphy's law, the log is cleared at the wrong time, but yes, that's what I'd do if there is no better solution; maybe with an internal counter to tell when to clear.  I think Firebug has some limit.

Comment: make your own logger that dumps into the console on request

Comment: ^ This, on request or on a regular interval.

Comment: @JanDvorak, sounds like a sensible solution. But the logger complicates everything -- I'd have to deep-clone each object, which is a performance hog if written in JS.

Comment: @arch you wouldn't have to clone anything, because chrome doesn't either. And if you do want to preserve the object contents, `JSON.stringify` is your best bet.

Comment: @JanDvorak looks like "normal" Chrome and Safari web browsers load objects on first expansion, however, Qt 5.5 WebKit behaves differently for whatever reason; it evaluates objects at the time of logging and displays the first bits in a summary, which is pretty useful. `JSON.stringify()` will only work correctly and reversibly for serializable, acyclic structures without functions etc. So I guess I'll either go with lazy evaluation on expansion or periodic clearing. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While some JavaScript developer tools might implement an internal limit, WebKit's Web Inspector apparently does not, at least it does not expose any documented interface to it.

So basically there are two feasible solutions (besides patching WebKit or using a tool that supports a limit), as [Cerbrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1835379/cerbrus) and [Jan Dvorak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499214/jan-dvorak) have also mentioned.

- Create a proxy to the various `console` methods to buffer any log output and dump on request only, and limit the internal buffer.
  A simple ring buffer is not very fast, so an alternative would be to use two buffers where the older one is discarded and overwritten when the current becomes full.
  The drawback of using a buffer is that you cannot immediately expand objects but only on first access, which may lose vital debug data if they get overwritten (Qt 5's console expands simple objects and arrays *during* logging).
- Periodically clear the console to limit memory usage.
  However, the console may be cleared at the wrong time.